# man command not showing output

Tags: manpage

my man command has quit working no output or error message and not sure how I managed to muck it up. However, if I type `sudo man [item]` it works. I tried running mandb and that didn't work. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Output of man w/o sudo:

```
~$man man
~$
```

Other info:

```
~$type -a man 
man is /usr/bin/man
~$echo "$MANPAGER"

~$manpath -g 
/usr/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/X11R6/man:/opt/man

~$manpath -c
/home/damien/anaconda3/man:/var/cache/man/oldlocal:/var/cache/man/local:/var/cache/man:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/man
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add the output of `type -a man; echo "$MANPAGER"` to the post, please.

Comment: Also, use a copy and paste for the text you are giving in your picture.  Using real text rather than pictures of text is easier to read.

Comment: The full output of `PIPELINE_DEBUG=1 man --debug man` will likely be useful.

Comment: Hey @ddivittorio!!! I know this is pretty old question but are you still facing this issue?